# trying to draw circles based on distance between points

Tags: r, geometry, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to draw some circles and I was sort of hoping they would intersect with some points, alas...

```
library(maptools)
library(plotrix)
xy <- matrix(runif(20, min = -100, max = 100), ncol = 2)
distance <- spDistsN1(xy, xy[1, ])
plot(0,0, xlim = c(-100, 100), ylim = c(-100, 100), type = "n")
points(data.frame(xy))
points(xy[1, 1], xy[1, 2], pch = 16)
draw.circle(xy[1, 1], xy[1, 2], radius = distance)
```

The above code does the following:

- Create 10 random points and choose one (first) point that would serve as an "anchor".
- Calculate distance from anchor to all other points. This will be our "radius"
- Draw circles around anchor point using above calculated distances for radii.
- Scratch head why circles don't intersect with points that were used to calculate radii.
  [image: circles don't intersect with points used to calculate distance]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the old aspect ratio problem that comes up from time to time when people are drawing ellipses, circles, etc.

- [Drawing non-intersecting circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587794/drawing-non-intersecting-circles)

Substituting `MASS::eqscplot` for `plot` (**edit**: or using `asp=1`: see `?par`) appears to solve the problem.

Comment: adding `asp=1` will only work (I think) when (as in this case) the x and y ranges are identical, `eqscplot` should work slightly more generally.

Comment: The only difference I notice is that whe using `asp = 1` the ratio is preserved (image is proportionally grown/shrunk) while in `eqscplot` it gets deformed if you resize the window. Nice find, thanks!