# Why does an ellipse change orientation when the graphics window is not square?

Tags: r

The code snippet below creates bivariate normal data, plots it and then plots an ellipse along with the line y=x

```
require(ellipse); require(MASS)

mu    <- c(30,30)
Sigma <- matrix(c(900,630,630,900),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
dt    <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=1000,mu,Sigma))
names(dt) <- c("x","y")


plot(dt$x,dt$y)

df_ell <- data.frame(ellipse(cor(dt$x, dt$y), scale=c(sd(dt$x),sd(dt$y)), centre=c(mean(dt$x),mean(dt$y))))
lines(df_ell)
abline(a=0,b=1)
```

The line y=x should pass through the major axis of the ellipse due the covariance structure and the equal means.

In a square graphic window, everything seems fine:
[image]

However, if the window is resized to make it no longer square, the ellipse seems to orient itself away from the line:

[image]

What is causing this to happen and is it expected behaviour ?

Comment: Draw the `y=x` line. What's the angle between the line and the `x` axis? Then resize the window, like you did in this question. What's the angle now?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587794/drawing-non-intersecting-circles , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322603/trying-to-draw-circles-based-on-distance-between-points ; `MASS:eqscplot` may be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an optical illusion. Ellipses look a bit strange when the coordinates aren't square.

---

Note that your ellipse is based on the estimates from the sample, rather than the true underlying values, so it's not quite aligned properly to start with.

```
df_ell2 <- data.frame(ellipse(0.7, scale=c(30,30), centre=c(30,30)), npoints=101)
```

Now plot the ellipse with tangent lines as well as its major axis:

```
plot(dt$x,dt$y)
lines(df_ell2)
abline(0, 1)
abline(df_ell2[1,1]*2, -1)
abline(df_ell2[51,1]*2, -1)
```

[image: ellipse with major axis and tangents]

Hopefully the tangent lines let you see that the ellipse is properly aligned, but skewed by the aspect ratio.

Comment: Another possibly-helpful thing to observe is that the set of points that lie exactly on the ellipse is the same on the square plot as on the oblong plot.