# Drawing circles in R

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

I'm using plotrix package to draw circles.

And I don't get what is wrong with my code... :-(

I have three points. The first point `(1,1)` should be the center of the circle. The following two points `(1,4)` and `(4,1)` have the same distance/radius to the center.
So the circle in the plot should go through these points, right?

And I don't know why the circle looks wrong. Is there an explanation?

```
  p1 <- c(1,1)
  p2 <- c(4,1)
  p3 <- c(1,4)
  r <- sqrt(sum((p1-p2)^2))

  plot(x=c(p1[1], p2[1], p3[1]),
       y=c(p1[2], p2[2], p3[2]), 
       ylim=c(-5,5), xlim=c(-5,5))
  draw.circle(x=p1[1], y=p1[2], radius=(r))
  abline(v=-5:5, col="#0000FF66")
  abline(h=-5:5, col="#0000FF66")
```

Take a look at the produced output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiDCP.png)

Comment: set the aspect ratio `asp` in `?plot`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Baptiste says above, you can use `plot(...,asp=1)`. This will only work if your x and y ranges happen to be the same, though (because it sets the *physical* aspect ratio of your plot to 1).  Otherwise, you probably want to use the `eqscplot` function from the `MASS` package.   A similar issue arises whenever you try to do careful plots of geometric objects, e.g. [Drawing non-intersecting circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587794/drawing-non-intersecting-circles)

This plot is produced by substituting `MASS::eqscplot` for `plot` in your code above:

[image]

Note that depending on the details of what R thinks about your monitor configuration etc., the circle may look a bit squashed (even though it goes through the points) when you plot in R's graphics window -- it did for me -- but should look OK in the graphical output.

Comment: Thanks! The MASS eqscplot function is close to what I need.
Still, it would be nice to be ablte to define own xlim and ylim.

Comment: The tricky part is that you're typically juggling (1) the dimensions of the plotting device (typically user-adjustable, but not adaptive from within R's graphic framework); (2) dimensions of the figure region within the plotting region (depends on margins and sizes of titles, annotations, etc.); (3) user x- and y- limits. With care, you can get these the way you want them, but it's a bit hard to get it all adjusted automa[gt]ically ...